# FakeItEasy - faking assignment

Tags: c#, unit-testing, configuration, fakeiteasy

I have Some code where I have a fake configuration root. I would like to check that a call is made to set a config value.

```
var fakeConfigRoot = A.Fake<IConfigurationRoot>();

//Do something that will set config item

//A call to set the config must have happened
```

It is possible to fake getting a config item using

```
 A.CallTo(() => fakeConfigRoot["TestConfigItem"]).MustHaveHappened(Repeated.Exactly.Once);
```

I would like to know if it is possible using FakeItEasy to fake the assignment of a config item and if so how. If it is not possible can anyone think of any workarounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to [specify a call to a property setter](http://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/specifying-a-call-to-configure/#specifying-a-call-to-a-property-setter) using `A.CallToSet`. The examples don't show it, but the syntax works for an indexer as well. Try this:

```
var fakeConfigRoot = A.Fake<IConfigurationRoot>();

fakeConfigRoot["animal"] = "hippo";

A.CallToSet(() => fakeConfigRoot["animal"]).MustHaveHappened(Repeated.Exactly.Once);
```

Comment: Thank you very much exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: I'm happy the answer helped. And the feature was fun to implement as well!

Comment: So bloody simple it painful, easy to over think this one.  Thanks mate.